# Using useDelimiter() to join substrings

Tags: java

My method `readDataFromFile()` can read text files like:

```
Bird    Golden Eagle    Eddie
Mammal  Tiger   Tommy
Mammal  Lion    Leo
Bird    Parrot  Polly
Reptile Cobra   Colin
```

The first column is the 'Type' of animal, second column is 'Species' and third is 'Name'.

**Current Output:**

```
Bird  Golden Eagle  < (Golden and Eagle count as different substrings).
    Mammal  Tiger Tommy
    Mammal  Lion Leo
    Bird  Parrot Polly
    Reptile  Cobra Colin
```

- How would I use the `useDelimiter` method to make 'Golden Eagle' count as one species?

**Current Code:**

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
       {
       String type = scanner.next();
       String species = scanner.next();
       String name = scanner.next();
       System.out.println(type + "  " + species + " " + name);
       scanner.nextLine();

       addAnimal( new Animal(species, name, this) );
       }
```

Comment: there is a tab space gap between bird and golden and between golden and eagle one space gap. Please use your delimiter as a tab space. This will fix your issue

Comment: The delimiter should be a tab

Answer (score 2):

> the first line has 'Golden Eagle' both separated by a tab

That is not correct.

The [source of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/6896b223-b6fa-4f78-aef1-083e8c0a6b3e/view-source) shows that the columns are all separated by a tab character (`\t` aka `\u0009`), but `Golden` and `Eagle` are separated by a *space* character (`\u0020`).

Do not read your file using `Scanner`. It is very slow and not the appropriate tool for parsing your file. Instead, use a `BufferedReader` and the `readline()` method, then `split()` the line into columns.

*Demo*

```
try (BufferedReader in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("animals.txt"))) {
    for (String line; (line = in.readLine()) != null; ) {
        String[] values = line.split("\t");
        for (String value : values)
            System.out.printf("%-15s", value);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
Bird           Golden Eagle   Eddie          
Mammal         Tiger          Tommy          
Mammal         Lion           Leo            
Bird           Parrot         Polly          
Reptile        Cobra          Colin
```

As you can see, the `Golden Eagle` text did not get split.

Comment: I tested the code and it works fine, however what if i had no choice but to use the useDelimiter method, as part of a project? how would i go about this?

Comment: @MelissaStewart `useDelimiter("\t|\\R")`, i.e. split tokens on tabs and [line breaks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending). However, it's a very bad idea, because a single bad line with incorrect number of columns would corrupt the reading of the rest of the file. Read *lines*, then parsing each line separately, would allow ignoring a single bad line while continuing to parse the rest without issue.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is just set correct column delimeter as *regexp* to the `Scanner`. In the following example I have set `\t` as column delimeter with `\n` as new line delimeter:

```
public static List<Animal> readAnimals(InputStream in) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("./animals.txt"))) {
        scan.useDelimiter("[\\t|\\n]");

        List<Animal> animals = new LinkedList<>();

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            animals.add(new Animal(scan.next(), scan.next(), scan.next()));
        }

        return animals;
    }
}
```